# Is it possible to have two mainClass in the pom.xml or be able to run two classes in the same pom.xml?

Tags: java, xml, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I am working on a java project. We use Continuous Integration with maven 3, svn and Jenkins. We have one utility java project in which we've implemented some useful features. We build a jenkins tasks to run the mainClass in this project. Here is the code snippet on project pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
           ..
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.ent.uti.Cleaner</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>value1</argument>
                        <argument>value2</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This class is execute in jenkins task configuration :

```
mvn exec:java -o -f cleaner/pom.xml
```

I am wondering if it is possible for me to implement some features in the same project and add another task in Jenkins ?
Is it possible to have two main classes in the same pom.xml configuration ?

I know i could create another project and configure a mainClass in the pom. I think doing so is not a good idea. The both task are independant so it's not suitable to run the both class one after another.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You could use multiple `<execution>` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use profiles for that purpose. All details are available here : http://www.jpeterson.com/2009/08/25/using-a-maven-profile-to-run-a-test-program/

Then your command line will look like :

```
mvn -P program1 exec:java -o -f cleaner/pom.xml

mvn -P program2 exec:java -o -f cleaner/pom.xml
```

Comment: Thanks i am cheking it

Comment: Nomoa thank for your answer. But  i am facing another problem. The mvn command already use a profil option to load different file configuration ( here profile are defined in settings.xml). I think i have to search another solution. perhaps to create another project.

Comment: You can activate multiple profiles in the command line: mvn -Pprof1,prof2. you can also look at the solution proposed by @chrylis (see his comment)